# Label / Legend on plot where curve deviates from 0

Tags: matlab

I have a dataset with 14 different sets of data i want to compare in a plot, but i cannot tell them apart. Is it possible to put a label next to where each line separates from 0?

[image]

Comment: do you have 14 x-coordinates for these events?

Comment: @Shai: I have 100 data-points for each of the lines. So it may look like: [ 15 10 5 0 0 0 0 ]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two parts to this problem:

First, find where the line converges to zero. This can be done using something simmilar to the following:

```
idx = find(line_data == 0, 1, 'first');
```

Second, label the line probably using the [text](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/text.html) function. The example given on the Matlab documentation page, should be close to what you want and should look something like:

```
text(idx, 0, '\downarrow Foo', 'VerticalAlignment', 'bottom');
```

Which produces something which looks like this:
[image: Example of label on plot]